# How to satisfy a protocol which includes an initializer?

Tags: swift, initialization, initializer

I defined a simple class:

```
class MyClass {
    var name:String?

    required init() {
        println("init")
    }
}
```

I can add a new initializer in an extension like this:

```
extension MyClass {
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.

**But** as soon as I define the new initializer in a protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    init(name:String)
}
```

And make my extension conform to that protocol:

```
extension MyClass : MyProtocol {
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Initializer requirement 'init(name:)' can only be satisfied by a
> `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'MyClass'

**What is going on here?**

(BTW: I can't make my class `final`, because this is only the extract of a more complicated use case.)

Comment: This might be an issue at the moment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1057171#1057171

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

To guarantee that all subclasses conform to `MyProtocol` new initializer has to be marked as `required` as well.

Furthermore Swift requires to declare all required initializers directly within the class and does not allow to declare them in extensions.

```
extension MyClass : MyProtocol {
    required convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: I concur: as soon as I copy-pasted my extension into the class itself, everything worked.

Comment: I don't understand. Would you show your code after the fix?

Comment: I followed this answer and got `required convenience` initializer. Wow.

Comment: it is not working for me: 
required' initializer must be declared directly in class "MyClass"'